# Who will decide the "specified number of pods" for replication controller in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

"A replication controller ensures that a specified number of pod "replicas" are running at any one time. "  As it is said,  who will decide the "specified number of pods" for replication controller?  It seems like that we can set the number. And is there any auto-scaler who will did this thing?

Answer (score 0):

The person who creates (or updates) the replication controller decides.

There is no autoscaler yet, but it is something the community [will be looking at post-1.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/proposals/autoscaling.md).

edit: Autoscaling is now available for the number of pods in replication controllers:  http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler/

Comment: thanks. I'm curious about what kind of scaling strategy the auto-scaler will use. And do u know any info about when will this version be released?

Comment: The doc I linked to discusses some strategy ideas. It won't be released anytime in the next month, but probably sometime early in the fall.

Comment: thank you. And here's my another question,so we know that the premise of auto-scaling is load balancing.I know there's a Round-Robin way in proxy, is there any algorithm used in K8s so doing load balancing?